# How do scale up/down a running Flink cluster on kubernetes with flink 1.11?

Tags: apache-flink, kubernetes-helm, flink-streaming

I'm running Flink on Kubernetes and when I update the replicas of TaskManager deployment, Kubernetes scales up/down the number of TM pods for me, but when I checked TM is up but the newly added Tm is not getting any task not sure if that is all I need to do. Do I need to do anything else to make the job adapt to the more/less TMs in flink 1.11.3 version

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work the way you expected, upgrade to Flink 1.13 and use reactive mode. See https://flink.apache.org/2021/05/06/reactive-mode.html.

With Flink 1.11, you'll have to rescale manually, by restarting from a checkpoint or savepoint while specifying the new parallelism. If you are using a [native kubernetes deployment](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/deployment/native_kubernetes.html), Flink will use its kubernetes resource manager, and will create the appropriate number of pods automatically. (Note that native kubernetes deployments have also been improved since 1.11.) On the other hand, with a standalone kubernetes deployment, Flink is unaware of kubernetes, and you're on your own, and need to manually create the right number of pods.

Comment: Yes we could have update to 1.13 but iceberg does not support 1.13 yet if I am not wrong